# Centralising nested Divs which have onclick elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 rows, one which needs two images and the other which needs to show information if those images are clicked.

I'm having an issue centralising the images and text within the row div.

```
    <div id="container">
<!-- Image row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="badbutton"><a  href="#" onclick="showHide('bad')"></a></div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="goodbutton"><a  href="#" onclick="showHide('good')"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Text Row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="bad" style="display:none;">
            <p>Oh no! We'd appreciate it if you'd share your experience with us so we can improve in the future. Just click below to get started.</p>
            <p> FORM HERE </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="good" style="display:none;">
                <p>Fantastic! Please share your experience with the world on of these popular websites. Just make a selection below to get started.</p>
                <ol>
                    <li>Click here to review us on Google+ Reviews</li>
                    <li>Click here to review us on Facebook</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What's happening is the col-md-6 takes up 45% of the row div but the buttons inside aren't centralising themselves.

Here is the CSS:

```
.row {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-md-6 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.col-md-6 {
    width: 45%;
}
#good,
#bad {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Here is the outcome:

[image]

Comment: create a fiddle to get exact issue

Comment: Are you using twitter bootstrap, if so which version?

Comment: @abhiklpm I used the row and column elements from the standard bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try using display:table-* it will make your elements behavior like a table.

```
.row {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: table-row;
}

.col-md-6 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;

  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Hey, so doing this made the text underneath look a lot nicer, but the images aren't aligning in the middle.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your issue? It will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

Give style "text-align:center" to the "col-md-6" div. And display: inline-block to #goodbutton and #badbutton.

Just for example

```
#badbutton, #goodbutton {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
display: inline-block;
background: #444;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

Sample fiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lw27ofb1/

Comment: I dont see the images in the fiddle. Just try the solution. It should work

Comment: The images were replaced with background colors. I have tried to solution. It didn't work

Comment: Updated the answer. Not sure if that is what you want.